# Concat IDs in one column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using multiple join query in Mysql,

```
Table A
IdA  
name 

Table B 
idB
name
A_id
```

Is there a possible way to build request that returns
idA name VIRTUAL_FIELD

VIRTUAL_FIELD contains all the IDs of table B referenced to table A ?

For example

```
Table A
IdA  : 1
name  : Bananas

Table B 
idB : 1
name : I
A_id : 1

idB : 2
name : K
A_id : 1

idB : 3
name : D
A_id : 1
```

My request returns

```
IdA  : 1
name  : Bananas
VIRTUAL_FIELD : 1,2,3  or [1,2,3] etc..
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sure, use `group_concat` -- this has to be a duplicate question though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT A.IdA, A.name, GROUP_CONCAT(B.idB) as VIRTUAL_FIELD 
  from TABLE A INNER JOIN TABLE B 
   ON B.A_id=A.IdA GROUP BY A.IdA
```

use group concat and group by